# gunicorn (uvicorn). run programatically or via command line?

Tags: python, gunicorn, uvicorn

Is there any difference if I run uvicorn (gunicorn) programatically or via command line in production environment?

command line:

```
uvicorn --host ${HOST} --port ${PORT} --workers ${NUM_OF_WORKERS} --log-config ${FILE_PATH}
```

programatically

```py
uvicorn.run(
  'main:app', host=host, port=port, reload=False,
  workers=workers_num, log_config=log_config
)
```

```
python main.py
```

Comment: You basically wrote a poor man's `uvicorn` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer by myself according to hint from [@Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d)

`uvicorn` executable file is:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from uvicorn.main import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Where `main()` is:

```py
def main(
  ...
  many_arguments_here
  ...
) -> None:
  sys.path.insert(0, app_dir)
  run(app, **kwargs)
```

So, if we run `uvicorn` programatically like

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys

  # app_dir default value if nothing set
  app_dir = "."
  sys.path.insert(0, app_dir)
  sys.exit(
    uvicorn.run(
      'main:app', host=host, port=port, reload=False,
      workers=workers_num, log_config=log_config
    )
  )
```

That will be same as run `uvicorn` via command line